# Broadcast Receivers - SMS and Phone calls

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I want to design an app that will make the LED blink whenever a message or a phone call is received. I've read about broadcast receivers but I'm not sure how to work with them or where to start.

If anyone can put me in the direction where I can perform an action whenever phone rings? Maybe a small example or tutorial link would be nice.

Regards
Saeed

Comment: This should help you get started: http://bit.ly/RNUZaH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help with the broadcast receiver stuff: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html

This should help with LED stuff (half way down):
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-vibrator/